# Find a file in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to find a file in a directory using Kotlin. Something like:

ls *.bld

If there are a couple results, that's ok. It would be a short list. Now there's thousands of files.

Comment: Can you add the code you used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a File object for a directory and then [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) on the [walk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/walk.html).

```kotlin
val path = File("/path/to/files/directory")
path.walk().filter { it.name.endsWith(".bld") }
```

**PS: walk() returns a [Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/) of contents of directory**

Comment: I believe the path has SO many files to walk through, a Java heap space error is occurring with the shear size to be filtered. Is there another way to search through without using memory?

Comment: @DavidPesetsky its potentially because there are too many File objects, try `val filteredFilesPath = path.map { it.absolutePath }.filter { it.endsWith(".bld") }.toList()`

Comment: Since [sequences are cold](https://kotlinlang.org/assets/images/reference/sequences/sequence-processing.png), every object will go through this process before another object comes in existence and only strings(absolute path) are stored in the list.

Comment: I'll try that. How do I print filteredFilesPath ? I'm new to Kotlin :)

Comment: @DavidPesetsky filteredFilesPath is just a list containing absolute paths of the files. you could just println() on that

Comment: It doesn't build. Doesn't seem to like map?   val path = File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))     val filteredFilesPath = path.map { it.absolutePath }.filter { it.endsWith(".bld") }.toList()

Comment: @DavidPesetsky whoops, forgot the walk, `val filteredFilesPath = path.walk().map { it.absolutePath }.filter { it.endsWith(".bld") }.toList()`, map actually maps element by the lambda provided, it creates a new collection changing each of the element by the return type of the lambda in our case is the absolute path (String).

Answer (score 0):

With kotlin there in build in [listDirectoryEntries](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/list-directory-entries.html)